# Recursively iterate over multiple arrays to concatenate the values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, recursion

Hi thanks for reading.

I have multiple "tag" (or chip) inputs with the ability to add more Tag Inputs. So a user could end up with say, 3 inputs, like this:

[image]

(they could have only two tag inputs, but with 4 or 5 tags each, or they could have 5 tag inputs with only 1 or 2 tags)

What I need is a list that matches each value with the other:

- red / small / mens
- red / large / mens
- green / small / mens
- green / large / mens
- red / small / mens
- red / small / ladies
- red / large / mens
- red / large / ladies
- green / small / mens
- green / small / ladies
- green / large / mens
- green / large / ladies

At the moment my code is static:

```
this.optionTypes[0].options.forEach((subOption: string) => {
  this.optionTypes[1].options.forEach((subOption1: string) => {
    this.optionTypes[2].options.forEach((subOption2: string) => {
      this.optionList.push({
        name: subOption + ' / ' + subOption1 + ' / ' + subOption2
      });
    });

  });

}
```

But I need to be able to recursively iterate over many of the inputs, regardless of how many options they add or tags they add within the options.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Yoshi: You had an interesting answer to this question, involving generators.  I didn't test, but it looked like it would work.  Why delete the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#n-ary_Cartesian_product) of the arrays.  There are several good ways to calculate these.  Here's a recursive version

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs = undefined
    ? []
  : xss.length == 0
    ? xs .map (x => [x])
  : xs .flatMap (x => cartesian (xss) .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))

console .log (
  cartesian ([
    ['red', 'green'],
    ['small', 'large'],
    ['mens', 'ladies'],
  ])
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But you could also write it using a double `reduce`, like this:

```js
const cartesian = ([x, ...xs]) => 
  (xs || []) .reduce (
    (a, b) => a .reduce (
      (c, d) => [... c, ... (b .map (e => [... d, e]))],
      []
    ),
    (x || []) .map (x => [x])
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide reproducable example of your code, I assume this should help:

```js
this.optionTypes.forEach((subOption: string) => {
    subOption.options.forEach((subOption: string) => {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Not sure you need to use recursion here