# How to apply a function to lists of values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, recursion

I have a two-dimensional array (sort of), filled with words. Number of columns differs from row to row. Like this:

```
var words = [
  ["foo", "bar"],
  ["end", "start", "finish"],
  ["block"],
  ["prefer", "pretty", "patty", "flock", "freeze"]
]
```

So, 4 rows. We take one word from each row and form a 4-word string. I need to print out all possible strings. How do I do it?

The expected result:

```
foo end block prefer
bar end block prefer
foo start block prefer
bar start block prefer
foo finish block prefer
bar finish block prefer
foo end block pretty
...etc
```

Comment: Same way you'd do it with same length arrays. It would be easier to switch the later words before earlier words.

Comment: You might want to search for "Cartesian Product".  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65252469/1243641) might work for you, although you'd have to `join` together the resulting arrays.

Comment: @ScottSauyet this looks very promising. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the following `sentence` function:

```js
const sentence = (a, b, c, d) => `${a} ${b} ${c} ${d}`;

sentence('foo', 'end', 'block', 'prefer');
//=> 'foo end block prefer'
```

As I understand it you have arrays that contains all the values for each parameter.

You can still work with the function above *without* modifying its signature. However you do need to *lift* it so that it can be applied to lists of values. For that I will use [ramda.js](/questions/tagged/ramda.js):

```js
const sentence = lift((a, b, c, d) => `${a} ${b} ${c} ${d}`);

console.log(

  sentence( ["foo", "bar"]
          , ["end", "start", "finish"]
          , ["block"]
          , ["prefer", "pretty", "patty", "flock", "freeze"]
          )

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>const {lift} = R;</script>
```

Comment: That's a nice use of `lift`.  I hadn't even considered that approach.  I wonder what would be the minimal useful implementation of `lift` for this case.

Comment: This might answer my previous comment: `const liftArrs = (fn) => (xs, ...xss) => xss .length == 0 ? xs .map (fn) : xs .flatMap (x => liftArrs ((...args) => fn (x, ...args)) (...xss))`.  Not nearly as generic as Ramda's version, but interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this as a visualization of a number. With normal base 10 every digit is between 0-10, thus 10 digits each place, but in your case there are 2 in the first, 3 in the second, only one in the third and 5 in the 4th.

So instead of:

```
...
[0, 0, 0, 8]
[0, 0, 0, 9]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
...
```

You want:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
...
```

So I made the least significant symbol the last element so that you can see it as a number, but if I were to program this I probably would have gone for keeping the digits in the index of the symbol array. The way you know it overflows is if the increment reaches the length of the index. eg. On the third line the lowest index would become the length of `["foo", "bar"]` which means it overflows and you need to continue until there i snot longer an overflow.

One you have managed to count like this you can transform any legal number to a string. eg. `[1, 2, 0, 0]` (reverse of 6th line) is `"bar finish block prefer"` and as you can see you just use the number as an index into the same index of your sybols array with the actual index of symbol being the number. eg. the `2` is in index `1` and it has the number `2` so you get it with `words[1][2]`.

Good luck!

*NB: This is a no code answer. I usually have no code answer when there is no code of an attempt in the question. IMHO this answers the question*

Answer (score 0):

You could modify [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65252469/1243641) I gave in another question to yield strings rather than arrays, like this:

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs = undefined
    ? []
  : xss.length == 0
    ? xs .map (x => [x])
  : xs .flatMap (x => cartesian (xss) .map (ys => `${x} ${ys}`))

const words = [["foo", "bar"], ["end", "start", "finish"], ["block"], ["prefer", "pretty", "patty", "flock", "freeze"]]

console .log (cartesian (words))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But I think it would be far better to keep `cartesian` intact and write a wrapper function around it like this:

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs = undefined
    ? []
  : xss.length == 0
    ? xs .map (x => [x])
  : xs .flatMap (x => cartesian (xss) .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))

const makePhrases = (wordLists) => 
  cartesian (wordLists) .map (words => words .join (' '))

const words = [["foo", "bar"], ["end", "start", "finish"], ["block"], ["prefer", "pretty", "patty", "flock", "freeze"]]

console .log (makePhrases (words))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

In any case, the appropriate search term for your question is "Cartesian Product".